# Get candidate using Indeed API

Tags: api

I wonder if there is a way to get candidates of my job ?
I look into the Indeed API : https://developer.indeed.com/ but doesn't seem to offer this possibility.
Does anyone has been through this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Indeed has announced that they will stop providing API for retrieving candidate application data from November 17th, 2021, so there is no way to accomplish this.